# How to escape variables with parentheses inside if-clause in a batch file?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, escaping

Running this batch file

```
@echo off
set a=some value with (parentheses) inside
if 1 == 1 (
    set PATH=%a%
)
```

gives `inside was unexpected at this time.` error.

How to escape `a` variable to avoid this error?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use two different ways

Use the extended syntax of `set` with quotes `set "var=content"` will set var with content,
content is quoted so special characters aren't problematic and it uses the content till the last quote (without the quote itself)

```
@echo off
set a=some value with (parentheses) inside
if 1 == 1 (
    set "PATH=%a%"
)
```

Use delayed expansion (like the answer of shf301) but also transfer the value to the main scope.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set a=some value with (parentheses) inside
if 1 == 1 (
    set "localScope_PATH=!a!"
    rem now transfer it to the global scope
    FOR /F "delims=" %%A in ("!localScope_PATH!") DO (
       endlocal
       set "path=%%A"
    )
)
```

In this case the extended set-syntax is not necessary, I used it only to avoid hidden spaces at the line end.

**EDIT:**
*Can I combine this with setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion and using ! instead of % to lazy evaluate variable's value? When I tried I got )! was unexpected at this time.*

You can, but it's contra productive, as

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set a=some value with (parentheses) inside
if 1 == 1 (
    set PATH=!a:^)=^^^)!
    set path
)
```

Then your path contains carets in front of the `)` like
`C:\programs (x86^)`

To understand how expansion works you can read [SO:How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts/4095133#4095133)

**EDIT2: More problems with the path (containing quotes)**
According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33116937/call-with-spaces-and-paranthesis-in-path) there can occour another problem with parenthesis when the path contains quotes.

Sample
`path="C:\Program Files (x86)";C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype`

This is allowed, even it's not necessary to use quotes here, but this destroys the extended `SET` syntax, as now `set "newPath=%path%"` expands to

```
set "newPath="C:\Program Files (x86)";C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype"
```

Now at least one parenthesis is not inside quotes and is able to break a command block.

But you can simply remove all quotes from the path variable, as said, quotes aren't necessary here.

```
set "newPath=%path:"=%"
```

Comment: `set "var=content"` - who could have guessed? :)

Comment: *In this case the extended set-syntax is not necessary* Could You explain?

Comment: I prefer it, as it avoid problems with hidden spaces at the line end

Comment: I was asking why it's not necessary not what was the reason You used it :)

Comment: btw, could I somehow contact You?

Comment: Try to explain No2: it isn't necessary, as the delaye expansion is safe against special characters. I used it here only to show how many carets you would need.

Comment: Contact is possible via PM at dostips.com

Comment: I spent several hours trying to replace ) with ^) in variable before I found your help just to use set "var=content" instead of any replacements. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The `)` in `%a%` is the problem here. You can just do some substitution to escape the `)`.

```
@echo off
set a=some value with (parentheses) inside
if 1 == 1 (
    set PATH=%a:)=^)%
)
```

Comment: Can I combine this with `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and using `!` instead of `%` to lazy evaluate variable's value? When I tried I got `)! was unexpected at this time.` error.

Comment: You can combine it, but it's not necessary as delayed expansion is safe against any special characters, also `)`

Comment: I would use either delayed expansion or my method, not both. Just an opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Using delayed expansion will fix that:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set a=some value with (parentheses) inside
if 1 == 1 (
    set PATH=!a!
)
```

Without delayed expansion the if block (from the `if` to the ending `)`, %a% is replaced first and then the block is parsed and run.  With delayed expansion !a! isn't expanded after the block parsed.  So the parsing logic won't see the ) in `a` and won't cause it issues.

Comment: Well, you modified **local** `PATH` variable. How are you going to *transfer* this value to global scope?

Comment: In my answer is a sample to transfer variables to global scope

Answer (score 3):

Brackets and variables are always a pain to mix.  Use a subroutine instead.

```
@Echo Off
Set a=some value with (parentheses) inside
If 1 == 1 Call :SetPath
Echo %Path%
Exit /B

:SetPath
Set "Path=%a%"
SetX "Path" "%a%"
Exit /B
```

I set the variable twice, once using [Set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) for the current shell session, and one using [SetX](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) to set it system-wide for future shell sessions.  Remove either if they're unneeded.