# How to safely echo value of a variable inside if-clause skipping surrounding double quotes?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Running

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
set x=some value with unsafe (^&^<^>()") characters inside
if 1 == 1 (
  echo "value of x (!x!) is interesting"
)
```

gives

```
"value of x (some value with unsafe (&<>()") characters inside) is interesting"
```

I had to put the value being echoed inside double quotes to avoid parsing error. I don't want these double quotes to be printed, however. Is there any way to *temporarily* (only to safely pass it to `echo` command) quote value being printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is the same as in your question
[How to escape variables with parentheses inside if-clause in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883169/how-to-escape-variables-with-parentheses-inside-if-clause-in-a-batch-file)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
set x=some value with unsafe (^&^<^>()") characters inside
if 1 == 1 (
  set "output=value of x (!x!) is interesting"
  echo !output!
)
```

Comment: Well, it looks like this extended syntax of `set` with quotes is **the** building block of batch files... Is there any Microsoft document talking about this feature?

Answer (score 2):

you can add quotes to the variable and try a string substitution the moment you echo it.
with e.g.:

```
echo %x:"=%
```

but in your case i dont think that will work.
to make your example work just escape the parenthesis:

```
echo value of x ^(!x!^) is interesting
```

unfortunately there is no 100% answer for this.

let us know if it worked for you or you found a better solution

Comment: As you mentioned, it can't work, as the parser will fail at the brackets after the expansion of `%x:"=%`

Comment: However, that substitution will work with Delayed Expansion: `!x:"=!`.

Comment: @Aacini Substitution will replace all double quotes not only the surrounding ones, right?

Answer (score 2):

Excuse me, I think there is a little confusion here.

If you want to print any special character with an `echo` command just escape it. Period. Your problem have no relation with Delayed Expansion. For example, this code:

```
@echo off
if 1 == 1 (
  echo value of x (anything) is interesting
)
```

mark an error because the parentheses in echo command interfere with the opened `if`. To solve this, just escape the parentheses as weberik said:

```
@echo off
if 1 == 1 (
  echo value of x ^(anything^) is interesting
)
```

A Delayed variable Expansion never cause an error don't matter the value inside the variable.

Comment: +1, for showing that the problem isn't the delayed expansion nor the special characters in `x`

Comment: I was very aware of the fact that neither contents of variable `x` nor the use of delayed expansion were the cause of a problem. :) I left them just to make sure what I present is as close to my real code as possible. That's because oversimplifying when creating a test case is so easy.