# What is causing this Python syntax error?

Tags: python, django

I'm totally new to Python, and I'm trying to run my server but I'm getting this syntax error from the project I'm working on.

```
    def find_shortest_path(start: GraphNode, end, path=[]):
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

To be clear, I didn't write the code, I'm just supposed to style the project but I don't know how else to *see* the app without running it in the server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code appears to be using [function annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#function-annotations) which are only available in Python 3.X.

What [version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917885/which-version-of-python-do-i-have-installed) of Python are you using?

Comment: I'm using...Python 2.7.10 (when I run python -V) I don't know what version the app uses?

Comment: @JustusEapen can you provide more information about what app it is? I suspect if you install python3 and use that to start the django app, it will work.

Comment: installing Python 3 on my machine? I can give you more details on the app offline if you have time...

Comment: Ok I'm installing python3. Thanks all.