# Python beginner question! Why syntax error?

Tags: python, syntax

I am fairly new to Python, I have just finished setting it up 
on Visual Studio Code, and chose the right course..

yet with the following exercise i got a syntax invalid error,

```
my_name = "First Name"
print(f"My name is{my_name}.")
```

what am I messing?

The error:

```
File "c:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Pie\Hello.py", line 2
  print(f"Let's talk about {my_name}.")
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What exact version of Python are you using? Your version may not support string interpolation (`f""`).

Comment: @Carcigenicate python 3.6.0 64-bit

Comment: If you find that fstrings are not working, you're probably using a version of Python before 3.6. You should include the text of the syntax error in your question.

Comment: What is the exaxt error? It should include a `^` that points to where the error is.

Comment: Strange, make sure you're not using 2.7.X python version. This looks to me like a classic 2.7.x python version problem

Comment: When asking questions about errors, always include the copy-pasted (as text) full and complete error message. Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: try importing sys and print out sys.version. You can see what python version you are running.

Comment: @khelwood  I have included the error, I am sure I have downloaded python from the website.

Comment: @Barmar included it in Q

Comment: @Misha Just because you've downloaded Python 3.6 does not mean that you are _using_ Python 3.6.

Comment: @GabrielPanza I had 2.7 installed before and used it on notepad++ , now I shifted to VS and Python 3, I read earlier it's okay to have both versions installed.

Comment: @Misha you have to make sure by looking in console which version you are using

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917885/which-version-of-python-do-i-have-installed for how to find out the actual version you're running.

Comment: Just a random question.. what do you really want to do? Do you really need to use the "f" method instead of ```print("%s" % name)```?

Comment: @akhavro I am using it because it is recommended since I am going to be operating python 3.. 
and it is used throughout the book I am learning from.

Comment: @Misha I just asked because since you're a beginner, and this problem apparently is really due to the python version you're using, maybe it would be wiser to use the "old-style" prints instead of focusing too much effort on this. But ofc, it's your call. There is no advantage in using one print() way or another, except the readability. Will leave you now ;) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would write the code like this:

```
my_name = "First Name"

print("My name is " + my_name + ".")
```

It looks very easy and it is, but this would work.

Answer (score -4):

I would recommend using the following syntax:

```
print("My name is %s" %my_name)
```