# How to programmatically extract the Python version in a shell script?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

With the `python --version` as input in the terminal, I'd like to confirm (also in the shell in the form of shell programming) whether any python versions installed are 3 or higher. For example,

```
Python 3.2.1
```

Would yield `True` or some form of confirmation, where as 
`python2.2p1` or `Python 2.1.4` would yield `False`.

I've tried using regex through sed or grep, but can't get it.

Note, this is a different matter from what some think to be a duplicate of, as I'm asking the shell programming code that can automate confirmation of python3 or higher being installed, not a way to manually check it (just entering `python --version`).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917885/which-version-of-python-do-i-have-installed

Comment: Isn't that the output when Python is *not* installed?

Comment: In your case it seems like python is not installed at all. To capture this case you should ask your package manager instead of using `python -V`. Which package manager do you use? is it `apt`? Also, if you want to use version 3 then call `python3` instead of just `python`.

Comment: This output is from the [Ubuntu `command-not-found`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/command-not-found) hook for Bash. It should not even run from within a script, to my understanding.

Comment: Oops. You're right. Edited.

Comment: This is not a dupe, at least not of the chosen dupe target.  The question here is not how to get Python to report its version (the subject of the dupe target and all its answers), but rather *how to write a shell script* that interprets that (and perhaps other) output.

Comment: This sounds like an extremely trivial task - [edit] your question to show what you have tried and state what part do you need help with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> With the python --version as input in the terminal, I'd like to confirm (also in the shell in the form of shell programming) whether any python versions installed are 3 or higher.

If the `python` command launches any version of cpython, then the output of `python --version` (to its stderr, not stdout) will have the form:

```
Python X.Y.Z
```

You can test that in a shell script like so:

```
if python --version 2>&1 | grep -q '^Python 3\.'; then
  # It's python 3 ...
else
  # It's not python 3; maybe not installed
fi
```

Note that the output you originally presented in the question indicated that Python was not installed at all.  The above approach will execute the `else` branch in that event.  Note also that it is possible for Python to be installed with a different name -- for example, on the system where I am typing this, `python` is Python 2.7.5, but Python 3.4.8 is available via the command `python3`.  You could extend the above to test some possible alternative names for Python 3, but you cannot safely, reliably, or efficiently perform an exhaustive test for whether Python 3 is installed at all, under any name or path.

Comment: On reconsidering, I think this should be the made the accepted answer, and my solution is over engineered considering the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this in Bash is using `sort -V`.

To solve the problem of comparing version strings in general in bash, here is an simple `compare()` function that accepts two arguments a and b and returns true if a <= b. And then some unit tests showing its validity for various Python version inputs:

```bash
# test.sh

compare() {
  local a=$1 ; local b=$2
  [ "$( (echo "$a" ; echo "$b") | sort -V | head -1)" == "$a" ]
}

test22p1() {
  compare "2.2p1" "3.0.0"
  assertTrue "$?"
}

test214() {
  compare "2.1.4" "3.0.0"
  assertTrue "$?"
}

test300() {
  compare "3.0.0" "3.0.0"
  assertTrue "$?"
}

test372() {
  compare "3.7.2" "3.0.0"
  assertFalse "$?"
}

. shunit2
```

Output:

```
▶ bash test.sh
test22p1
test214
test300
test372

Ran 4 tests.

OK
```

(Those unit tests assume that [shunit2](https://github.com/kward/shunit2) is installed of course.)

About the function:

It just echoes `$a` then `$b` on two separate lines, pipes into `sort -V`, and takes the head. If the head is equal to the left-hand side, true is returned ; otherwise if it is equal to the right-hand side, false is returned.

In your question you mentioned you really want to know if Python 3 or greater is installed, so you could modify it and have something like this instead:

```bash
python3_installed() {
  local a b
  a=$(python --version 2>&1 | perl -pe 's/python *//i') ; b=3
  [ "$( (echo "$a" ; echo "$b") | sort -V | head -1)" == "$b" ]
}
```

This function will compute the actual version of Python installed, and compare it to "3" using `sort -V` and return false unless 3 or greater is installed.

Note use of Perl there to do a case-insensitive regex search and replace. (Not all sed's have the case-insensitive ability.)

The great thing about doing it this way is you can then have readable code when you call it, like:

```bash
if python3_installed ; then
  # yes it is!
else
  # ...
fi
```

Finally, according to the docs for `sort -V` (from the BSD manual; POSIX doesn't specify a `-V` option, but most sorts seem to have it):

> ```
> `-V, --version-sort`
> ```
>
> Sort version numbers.  The input lines are treated as file names in form PREFIX VERSION SUFFIX, where SUFFIX matches the regular expression `(.([A-Za-z~][A-Za-z0-9~]*)?)*`. The files are compared by their prefixes and versions (leading zeros are ignored in version numbers, see example below).  If an input string does not match the pattern, then it is compared using the byte compare function.  All string comparisons are performed in C locale, the locale environment setting is ignored.

Answer (score -2):

Here is sample awk script to do the job:

```
echo $(python --version) | awk 'BEGIN{found="false"}/python-3/{found="true"}END{print found}'
```

Comment: That's a [useless use of `echo`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat#echo). And it does nothing to reveal which version you have.

Comment: echo is used to provide standard-out to awk. Without the echo command, awk requires input file.

Comment: No, you are completely mistaken. If Python prints the version information to standard output, the pipe feeds that to Awk's standard input just as well as from `echo`; and if it doesn't, your `echo` doesn't help at all.

Comment: ... and it doesn't.  `python --version` directs its output to stderr, not stdout.  Moreover, its error output when `python` is a version-3 cpython does not match `/python3/`.