# Nothing happens when writing python3 --version in cmd

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I wrote the following command in cmd : python3 --version
But, nothing happens. It's on windows. I use python 3.7 on Spyder, everything is working. But I need to install a package from cmd.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which version of Python do I have installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917885/which-version-of-python-do-i-have-installed)

Comment: Unless you have alias your python, in Windows, you have just `python`. To get different version you will change environment or use a tool to set specific python as a global python.

Comment: maybe you have other program/script with name `python3` and now it runs it. On LInux you could use `which python3` to get full path to this program and then you can see what is inside this program.

Comment: I tried python3 --version, python --version, python -V, etc. But each time, nothing happens, not even an error

Comment: it looks like prorgam which has only name `python3` but it is not real Python 3. Maybe you created program (`python3.exe`) or batch (`python3.bat`) with the same name and now it runs this program/batch - if this program doesn't get arguments then it will not show errors when you use `--version`. Find all files with `python3` in name.

Comment: I've got 2 programs named python.exe and python3.exe in C:\Users\benoi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps. I don't know what it is. And I can't erase those programs (it raises an error when I try)

Comment: You can use this command to find out what the command line interpreter would execute:  `where python3` - that will tell you the path to the `python3`.  From there you can diagnose whether there is a `.bat` or other alias getting between you and the real `.exe`.

Comment: `dir "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\*.exe"` (the path derived from `where python3`) gives me some `EXE`s of **zero length** incl. `python3.exe`, `ubuntu.exe`, `MicrosoftEdge.exe` etc. Honestly, I don't know what the hell Windows need those files… Use `python --version`.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving up the "python37" environment path and "python37\Script" at the top of list in environment variables.
Then run command>python --version

this worked for me.